# Ternary relationship between 3 entities is causing Entity Framework "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to figure out what I am doing out of the ordinary to cause the Update-Database command to tell me the following:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint

> 'FK_ProjectOwnerProduct_ProjectProduct_ProjectId_ProductId' on table
>   'ProjectOwnerProduct' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

and

> Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes.
>   The index 'PK_ProjectOwnerProduct' has maximum length of 908 bytes.
>   For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will
>   fail.

I have the following entity structure:

**3 top level entities:**
Project (PK: ProjectId)
Owner (PK: OwnerId)
Product (PK: ProductId)

**Many-to-Many join tables**
ProjectOwner (PK: ProjectId, PK: OwnerId)
ProjectProduct (PK: ProjectId, PK: ProductId)

**Handles the relationship between Owners and Products within a Project:**
ProjectOwnerProduct (PK: ProjectId, PK: OwnerId, PK: ProductId)

Here are my fluent API declarations:

```
        // ** KEY SPECIFICATIONS **
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwner>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.ProjectId, x.OwnerId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProduct>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.ProjectId, x.ProductId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwnerProduct>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.ProjectId, x.OwnerId, x.ProductId});

        // Project Owner
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwner>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Project)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProjectOwners)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwner>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Owner)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProjectOwners)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);

        // Project Product
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProduct>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Project)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProjectProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProduct>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Product)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);

        // Project Owner Product
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwnerProduct>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Project)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProjectOwnerProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwnerProduct>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Owner)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProjectOwnerProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwnerProduct>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Product)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);
```

If a Project is deleted I would expect that all of its ProjectOwners and ProjectProducts get deleted. Additionally all of its ProjectOwnerProducts.

If a ProjectOwner gets deleted I would expect all ProjectOwnerProducts that contain that ProjectId,OwnerId combo get deleted.

If a ProjectProduct gets deleted I would expect all ProjectOwnerProducts that contain that ProjectId,ProductId combo get deleted.

I don't see why it is complaining...

Comment: For the first error it sounds like an issue with cascading deletes (it sounds like it's on, but it needs to be off).  The second one sounds like the column types for the primary key are poor choices (wouldn't know because you haven't shown what they are).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I found that the first error was due to me having IList<ProjectOwnerProduct> ProjectOwnerProducts properties in both ProjectOwner and ProjectProduct entities. Removing these two lists fixed the issue, it had nothing to do with updating my Fluent API code. However, it does kind of suck that I can't query directly from ProjectOwner and ProjectProduct to give me all of the ProjectOwnerProduct entities just because of this cascade delete error. Currently with it working the only way I can access ProjectOwnerProduct is directly though the Project entity.